# AngularJS validation is not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS; can someone help me why the below code is not validating the form?

```
<form name="reviewForm" ng-controller="ReviewController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addReview(product);" novalidate>
    <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars" required>
        <option value="">Rate the Product</option>
        <option value="1">1 Star</option>
        <option value="2">2 Star</option>
    </select>
    <textarea ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.body"></textarea>
    <input type="email" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" required/>
    <div>ReviewForm is: {{reviewForm.$valid}}</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `novalidate` from your form.

You have `novalidate` at the beginning of your form which is disabling your browser's native form validation.

> Note that `novalidate` is used to disable browser's native form
>   validation.

See [HTML 'form' novalidate Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) and [Angular Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: This should be a comment because it's not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

@Milton I think there is no problem with your code, i have created a plunkr that also shows that there is not any issue with your code.
Here is the code i have written.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myctrl($scope) {
            $scope.review = {};
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <form name="reviewForm" ng-controller="myctrl as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addReview(product);" novalidate>
            <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars" required>
                <option value="">Rate the Product</option>
                <option value="1">1 Star</option>
                <option value="2">2 Star</option>
            </select>
            <textarea ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.body"></textarea>
            <input type="email" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.author" required/>
            <div>ReviewForm is: {{reviewForm.$valid}}</div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the plunkr link of the code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nVCmukG5abpi1Y4ZHkrq?p=preview

If the issue remains, can you give more description of data you are entering?

Comment: Actually, the code is working with validation, I missed to add 'no go' functionality is the 'addReview' function. Also If I enter email id like 'milton@yah' it shows no error or validation succeeds. Is this valid?

Comment: Hi @MiltonAin, The email id you entered can be valid or invalid depending upon how browser treats email component.  [Here](http://www.html5-tutorials.org/form-validation/validating-email/) is the link that explains it very well.

Answer (score 0):

At first step: Remove `novalidate` from your form
and add the submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="isFormValid(reviewForm) />
```

and in your .js:

```
 $rootScope.isFormValid = function (form) {
        return form.$invalid;
    };
```